# Add to Parent Group in Magento 2.2

Tags: xml, layout-update, magento2.2.2

How to assign any block to group `detailed_info` in magento using `<referenceBlock>` tag in magento 2.2?

In Magento 1.x it was like:

```
<action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
```

Can anyone help me out here, how to perform same thing in Magento 2.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue (tested on M2.2.7) and there is no option to handle that in the right way.

You can set/update `group` attribute only by `action` like this:

```
<referenceBlock name="YOUR_BLOCK">
    <action method="setAttribute">
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">group</argument>
        <argument name="value" xsi:type="string">detailed_info</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

But it will be processed during block generation, so basically it's useless since Magento operates on `group` attribute from XML node directly, before any actions are called on a block.

`\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Block::scheduleReference`
Is responsible for processing XML nodes and collecting information about them in:
`\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\ScheduledStructure::$scheduledData`

Inside `scheduleReference` method only `arguments` are evaluated but they are unable to change `attributes`.

The only solution I found is obvious (and ugly) and it assume changing the way how `details.phtml` collect child blocks - use `getChildNames` instead of `getGroupChildNames`.